# Displaying a Selected Value from a combo box into a textbox (or label) in c# without pressing a button

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to display a selected time from a combobox into a textbox in c#... the user clicks on a value from a combo box and the textbox automatically populates with the selected value... anyone know how to do this?

```
    //Method for combobox followed by method for textbox
    private void UnderGroundTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj.underground = UnderGroundTime.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void GrandTotalBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GrandTotalBox.Text = UnderGroundTime.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SelectedIndexChanged` Event of the combobox and set the textbox text in there like this:

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
 }
```